# Renaming files in bash in for loop with regular expression

Tags: shell-script, mv

I have files like the following:

`part-00001.lzo?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=recsys2021-website-service-acc%40twttr-recsys-2021-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210325%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20210325T183938Z&X-Goog-Expires=25`

`part-00002.lzo?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=recsys2021-website-service-acc%40twttr-recsys-2021-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210325%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20210325T183938Z&X-Goog-Expires=25`

.....

I want to rename them to:

`part-00000.lzo`
`part-00001.lzo`
.....

and delete the part after the extension `.lzo`.

I want to then concatenate them into 1 file chronologically and delete all compressed `.lzo` files.

Here is what I wrote:

```
 for f in  *.lzo\?*

 do
   mv $f * not sure what should I write here *
 done

 cat part-* > train.csv

 rm -rf part-*
```

I am not sure what I should write in place of the newly renamed file. Thanks

Comment: I'm struggling to see the point of renaming the files if you're simply going to delete them after concatenating - why not just concatenate them as-is?

Comment: yeah, I missed an important point. I had to decompress them using lzop after renaming them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to do the renaming:

```
for i in part*; do mv "$i" "${i%%.lzo*}.lzo"; done
```